# Image stretches vertically when using min-height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and the `img-responsive` class. I'm trying to place an image in the middle of a div and it works perfectly. However, for some screen sizes, I'd like the div/image to be a certain minimum height. However, when I set `min-height` the image stretches vertically to meet this height, but the width does not, so the image is distorted.

CSS

```
img#main-im14 {
    min-height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header-content-inner">
            <img id="main-im14" src="img/image.png" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

use `width: auto;` instead. Your current css is telling the browser to size the image to 100% of its container width **AND** stretch it to 500px tall as well, hence the distortion.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this seemed to have no effect. Do I need these styles on the image or the div?